# how to set up a dynamic text color with material ui, react

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

Is there a way one can set a dynamic text-color depends on component background-color,
using Material-UI API,

component A has Light BG => Dark Text,
component B has Black BG => Light Text

( I can achieve this using tinyColor API on single-components, looking for more general use case )

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `theme.palette.getContrastText()`